# How to seed Users in ASP.NET 5 Startup.cs with Async

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, async-await

I'm attempting to create an initial 'Super User' in an ASP.NET 5 application. Using the latest template files with MVC 6 / EF7.

I can follow the examples set out here:

http://wildermuth.com/2015/3/17/A_Look_at_ASP_NET_5_Part_3_-_EF7

This works fine - until I try to execute an async method. For example:

```
await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "P@55w0rd!");
```

or even:

```
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Synchronous methods work without a problem and this code executes outside of the `Startup.cs Configure{...}` as well.

I get the 'White Screen of Death' on application start. I would do it all without *async* but I don't think the UserManager has a `Create()`in Identity 3.0.

Is this me not understanding asynchronous programming or should it be possible?

**EDIT**: Added the entire call:

Define a `Seeder` class and a method to create the user:

```
  public class Seeder
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        public Seeder(
            ApplicationDbContext context,
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _context = context;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public async Task Seed()
        {
            await CreateUsersAsync();
        }

        public async Task CreateUsersAsync()
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync("superuser@superuser.com");

            if (user == null)
            {
                var company = _context.Company.First(x => x.Name == "Acme Ltd");

                user = new ApplicationUser
                {
                    UserName = "superuser@superuser.com",
                    Email = "superuser@superuser.com",
                    CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                    IsActive = true,
                    CompanyID = company.CompanyId
                };

                await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "P@55w0rd!!");

            }
        }
    }
```

Configure the service:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...
services.AddTransient<Seeder>();
...
}
```

Call it:

```
public async void Configure(Seeder seeder)
{
...
await seeder.Seed();
...
}
```

Funny thing is; it does actually create the User - it just doesn't continue. So the second time it executes `user != null` and it executes fine.

Comment: Could you please share the entire method call to the `_userManager.CreateAsnyc`? What does the controller code look like?

Comment: I believe the async calls in UserManager return an IdentityResult object, which indicates whether the method succeeded. In that object is a Result property, which holds your user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is because a deadlock is formed by the signature

```
public async void Configure(Seeder seeder).
```

Since it returns void, the awaited Task is never returned to the caller which creates a dead lock. Can you make it:

```
public async Task Configure(Seeder seeder).
```

I haven't gotten to work with MVC 6 yet, :( so I may be missing something. But that's why there is a deadlock.

Edit:

Since you can't change the signature of Configure, create a method called ConfigureAsync that returns type Task. Now await as per usual inside of it with your user manager code and call ConfigureAsync from Configure but wait on it.

```
ConfigureAsync.ConfigureAwait(false).Wait()
```

ConfigureAwait (false) is used to prevent potential dead locks of waiting on the async method to complete.

Full example:

```
public void Configure(Seeder seeder)
{
    //Edited due to typo/bad syntax.
    ConfigureAsync(seeder).Wait();
}

public async Task ConfigureAsync(Seeder seeder)
{
   //Now treat this like true async/await.
   await seeder.Seed().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

If you run into deadlocks here, perhaps your seeder should just be synchronous? I would avoid using Task.Run() in an ASP.NET context because that will totally defeat the purpose of async/await in the first place by taking up two request threads that would have just been done on one if done synchronously.

Comment: I don't think `Configure` can return _Task_. I get a 'The 'Configure' method in the type 'xxx.Startup' must have a return type of 'Void'.' error.

Comment: @jidl I have updated the answer to a solution that will help you call your async synchronously from the void configure. You basically need an async version of configure and synchronously call it from your original configure method.

Comment: That's worked - but `.Wait()` wouldn't compile. I took it out and used`ConfigureAsync(seeder).ConfigureAwait(false);` Edit the answer and I'll acceot it - Thanks!

Comment: @jidl I updated the answer, I goofed and put the configureAwait(false); on the wrong method call. You'll want to wait on ConfigureAsync(seeder), and use configureAwait(false) in the library method to help avoid potential deadlock.

Comment: Still no `Wait()` on the variable. What's the namespace for it?

Comment: You may be seeing an older edit, try a refresh. It's performing a ..Wait directly on the call to ConfigureAsync(seeder); Coffee had not yet entered my system this morning, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, you need to implement a sync interface but you only have async APIs available. There is no perfect solution.

Fortunately, this code is only called once so performance concerns don't matter. You can just do the dirty sync over async bridge:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ConfigureServicesImpl(services).Wait(); //bridge
}

public async Task ConfigureServicesImpl(IServiceCollection services)
{
   await ...;
}
```

You might need to insert a deadlock protection such as `ConfigureAwait(false)` or `Task.Run(() => ...).Wait()`.

Comment: Can ConfigureServices not be made Async Task? Or is that an implementation part of some other contract? Haven't gotten to use this yet, so I'm definitely missing part of that.

Comment: I assume you're implementing an interface or the method return type matters otherwise. In that you're stuck. Async methods require Task return type. Async void does not work because the caller will not be able to wait for completion.

Comment: As per my comment below I don't think that `Configure` can return _Task_. My `ConfigureServices` doesn't call `Configure` directly either (it was my understanding that it just registers services for DI purposes?). Where is `Configure` called from?

Comment: I don't really understand the code structure that you have because I can't see the interface and conventions you must implement. The important part of this answer is to wrap the async implementation with another method that does the async to sync bridge. Other patterns are possible. I find this one convenient because you only have to bridge once.